# scrartcl document class - page # on second page

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, classicthesis, cv, currvita

I am using the `scrartcl` document class to write my CV, but the page number on the second page has moved from the bottom of the page to a rather unsightly position at the top of the second page.

How can I move the page number back to the bottom of the page or remove it completely?

My document layout is below:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}    % classe article di KOMA
\usepackage[right=2cm]{geometry}

\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\MarginDate}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}}

\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}    % un buon pacchetto per CV
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % stile ClassicThesis
\usepackage{url}    % per gli indirizzi Internet
\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Blue}}
\renewcommand{\cvlistheadingfont}{\large}
\renewcommand{\cvlabelfont}{\qquad}
%Setup hyperref package, \& colours for links, text \& headings
\usepackage{hyperref}       
\hypersetup{    colorlinks,breaklinks,
        urlcolor=Maroon, 
        linkcolor=Maroon}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Summer 20070}

\newcommand{\NewWorkExperience}[3]

{\noindent\hangindent=0.7em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}

{\textit{#1}}\hspace{0em} #2 #3%
\vspace{0.1em}}

\newcommand{\Description}[1]

    {\hangindent=0em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize}

\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{0.6em}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Aveshen Pillay}}
\vspace{1.5em}

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Data}

\lipsum[2-4]

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Professional Experience}

\lipsum[2-4]

\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Unfortunately the example in your question does not work. At least `\begin{document}` is missing. And even with an added `\begin{document}` it throws several error messages. Please edit your question and improve the example to make it a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Without we cannot reproduce your problem to give you a good answer.

Comment: The errors are caused by the misused `\parbox{\datebox}...` lines.

Comment: Also your MWE doesn't recreate your problem.

Comment: @Skillmon - thank you for your help. I will edit the code for the MWE shortly. I just compiled it in TexStudio and it reproduced the error.

Comment: The page style is part of package `classicthesis`, which uses code not recommended for class `scrartcl`. If you do not want/need it, remove it. You can change the margins of your document either using KOMA-Script option `DIV` (see  [`scrguien.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)) or [package `geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). You can have spaced upper case or small caps using [package `microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype). You can have colors using [package `xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor).

Comment: @Aveshen Your example is a messy mix of many packages, but still: what you need is these two options in `\documentclass[ footinclude=true,headinclude=true] {scrartcl} `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want a page number and not other page header or footer, simply replace

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

by

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

`\thispagestyle` changes the page style of the current page only. `\pagestyle` changes the page style of all pages from the current one.

Nevertheless, I would recommend not to use `classicthesis`. Removing all not needed code and errors, you could use:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}    % classe article di KOMA
\usepackage[right=2cm]{geometry}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\MarginDate}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}}
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}    % un buon pacchetto per CV
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Blue}}
\renewcommand{\cvlistheadingfont}{\large}
\renewcommand{\cvlabelfont}{\qquad}
%Setup hyperref package, \& colours for links, text \& headings
\usepackage{hyperref}       
\hypersetup{    colorlinks,breaklinks,
            urlcolor=Maroon, 
            linkcolor=Maroon}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}% No page number on the first page
\begin{cv}{\textsc{\textls{Name Surname}}}
\vspace{1.5em}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

This would result in:

[image: with \thispagestyle{empty}]

or without `\thispagestyle{empty}`:

[image: without \thispagestyle{empty}]